# Sitecore - How to get User ID if the user was logged in using external identity provider (Salesforce SSO)

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, sitecore

I have a little bit of problem with the authentication on Sitecore website. Basically there is a button on the navbar, and when user clicks on the button, it redirects the same user to Salesforce to log in (Implementation of SSO). Basically I am using Salesforce as a **identity provider** and Sitecore Website as a **service provider**. Now I have a question? When user is logged, how can I get the ID of that user.
Do users in Sitecore User Manager have the same ID as the users in Salesforce, or I can just get a email to identify the user?

P.S: Sorry if this is a really stupid question, but I am a begineer when it comes to making Sitecore websites and the SAML SSO. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop with the Sitecore and Salesforce for a second, you'll need to cover some basics and click through the login process manually before you automate it.

You probably are using a "connected app" in Salesforce that includes OAuth2 config (consumer key also known as client id; a secret; a list of scopes telling what this app is allowed to do on behalf of this SF user; a list of allowed urls that can login using this consumer key and secret. Etc.) It might even have something about Canvas Apps at bottom of the page.

Next would be - who's logging in. A core Salesforce user or do you have Partner Community, Customer Community (recently rebranded to "Digital Experiences").

Open incognito window and go to https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/

For login host leave as is if you have production user or test.salesforce.com if you go from sandbox (you can also use branded urls, mycompany--dev.my.salesforce.com etc). If you have a community user you'll have to change the url to whatever is the community base url, like `https://dev-mycompany.cs123.force.com/mycommunity`

Don't change anything else, click next, next, next. This will take you through OAuth2 "[web server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm)" (one of many ways to log in). You type the username/password to SF screen and go back to that herokuapp with "authorisation code". The app has few minutes to swap that code for actual final "access token" and couple other pieces of info. Final step in this wizard calls OpenId "userinfo" - returning some info about the user that logged in. That's where you could pull the email if needed (and if there are extra fields you'd like SF to return in this process that's configurable too)

Close that browser window. Check the "connected app" in SF. Open new incognito window, do same thing but this time put your url, consumer key and secret (you might have to edit the app in SF first to allow callbacks to `https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/callback`).

So now you should have rough idea about whole login process. Your sitecore app probably does same thing, receives authorisation code and exchanges it for final token. At that point you have valid SF session ID you could use to call that "userinfo", run queries (if the app allowes API access, check the "scopes") etc.

I doubt the Sitecore developer created it all by hand, you probably have some Spring stuff like `spring.security.oauth2.client`... My Java days are long gone but if you get better at manual click-click-click through the flow you should be able to follow existing code?

It's a big topic and there are other ways to do it ([other OAuth flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5), sending info about the current user when you have external page embedded in SF as iframe, you'd need to read about "canvas apps")... but that's best guess based on info you provided. You might want to check some trailhead courses too like https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-connected-app-for-api-integration/implement-the-oauth-20-web-server-authentication-flow

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_auth_oauth.htm (Java but very hand-crafted raw HTTP, probably that Spring security is better)