# Build salesforce integration like hubspot or workbench

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I'm created a connected app in salesforce and consume contacts in my application, but for this, a need a consumer key from connected app.

I would like to create an application that consumes my customers' contacts without them having to create a connected app and generate a consumer key, in order to access their list

I saw this in a hubspot integration in salesforce, where it was possible to install a hubspot package and consume the contacts, I tried to create something on the appExchange but I was unsuccessful.
Can anyone tell me a tutorial for this? I've been searching for days and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

> without them having to create a connected app and generate a consumer
> key

Good. They don't have to. Have you actually tried connecting with 1 org's client id/secret to another org? Have you hit any issues?

Think about it. You're making a new awesome mobile app that connects to Salesforce. You'll want to make it work just like that, on any phone, any SF org, without org admins having to do any installation steps. You can generate OAuth2 keys in any org, even your personal Developer Edition. You could generate them in sandbox - but they'll be deleted when you refresh it.

Check if my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810951/313628 helps you understand the whole thing.

Now, there might be some things you do want in every org, maybe some config custom table... You'd have your mobile app and then maybe a Salesforce plugin published on AppExchange. But that's battle for another day and you don't need it for basic functionality.