# access_token pull issue after salesforce login in react-native. ( redirect_uri not working )

Tags: react-native, salesforce, redirect-uri

We have 2 domain in salesforce:
1-) https://gablesinsurancerecovery.my.salesforce.com
2-) https://gableinsurancerecovery.force.com

and we have 2 user:

- developer@cloudspade.com
- communitytest@cloudspade.com

  developer@cloudspade.com mail work with success on 1. domain but not work on 2. domain.
  Likewise, communitytest@cloudspade.com mail work with success on 2. domain but not work on 1.domain.

  Its not a problem. Problem is:
  2.domain is important to us. Because we have a react-native project by forcereact and we want work with community domain. ( 2. domain ). We setup with successfully this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zxMUrayFZ8&t=1634s
  We was work with perfectly with the video in the link for login.salesforce.com or 1. domain but doesn't work for 2. domain.
  Error is:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3wKf.png)

As seen in the photo we was see a page. But our expectation was that it would working we send redirect_uri. The redirect_uri we sent was to return "girApp://success" with an access_token and instance_url at the end. But we encounter a screen as you can see in the photo. Redirect is not working. Our goal is to access the access_token with redirection within the application after login and authorize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots to unpack here.

`***.my.salesforce.com` is your main domain, for internal users. `***.force.com` is for Customer/Partner Experience Cloud (formerly known as Communities, formerly known as Portal).

> developer@cloudspade.com mail work with success on 1. domain but not
> work on 2. domain

Out of the box Salesforce is perfectly fine with internal users logging in to community or even 1-click switching over from internal SF to community. Collaboration and all that. Your administrator probably marked only certain profiles / permission sets as community members, you'd need to check config. But it's possible to use the community login page, you guys just chose not to.

> communitytest@cloudspade.com mail work with success on 2. domain but
> not work on 1.domain

Yes. Community members must use community login page. They can't use generic login.salesforce.com, test.salesforce.com or your branded `***.my.salesforce.com`

> works perfectly with (...) login.salesforce.com or 1. domain but
> doesn't work for 2. domain

That's because most of the time the community login url must be full. Just the domain might not be enough for login because you can have up to 100 communities under same domain. You probably saw the example when you were enabling communities (Setup -> Digital Experiences -> Settings)

[image]

Go to Setup -> Digital Experiences -> All sites and write down the url you'll see there. It'll probably be something like `***.force.com/myportal`. That means that for API login you might have more luck with `***.force.com/myportal` than `***.force.com`.

Stop reading this answer now and go read [Sitecore - How to get User ID if the user was logged in using external identity provider (Salesforce SSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69799243/313628). Play with that OpenId Heroku app, once you get this to work with community user in the browser - you'll know which url to put in your react app. React developer might "like" this link too: https://gablesinsurancerecovery.force.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

It's kind of written in this article's footer: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_endpoints.htm&type=5

> Instead of using login.salesforce.com, you can also use the My Domain,
> Experience Cloud site, or test.salesforce.com (sandbox) domain in
> these endpoints. For hostname, use the My Domain, **Experience Cloud
> site**, or custom URL